# How do I reset the velocity variable of my object

Tags: javascript, object, html5-canvas, setinterval

How can I reset the velocity variable in my objects. I am making a canvas game, in which stars fall from the top of the Canvas. Problem is when I run the game in a setinterval() the velocity keeps getting greater and greater. What i want is the speed to stay the same unless i change it.

```
 function Star(x, y, rad, velocity, fill){
            this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999);//this create a random number between 0 and 599 on the x axis
            this.y = 0;
            this.rad = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 15);//this create a random number between 10 and 30 for the radius
            this.velocity = 5;
            this.fill = fill 

            this.draw = function(){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;                         
                ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
                this.y += this.velocity;
            }
        }

        function createMultipleStars(){
            for (var i = 0; i <= numOfStars; i++)
                stars[i] = new Star(i * 50, 10, i, i, "rgba(255,215,0,0.6)");
        }
        //createMultipleStars();

        function step() {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
            for (var i = 0; i<= numOfStars; i++)
                 stars[i].draw();
            requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }

       spaceShip.drawSpaceShip();
        var myVar = setInterval(function(){ init() }, 4000);


      function init(){
          createMultipleStars();
          step();
      }
```

Comment: create a fiddle will help

Answer (score 0):

Your frames per second were increasing with each interval.  Every four seconds another step function is added to the animation frame.  To fix this I added an fps counter and singleton pattern.  With the singleton pattern you shouldn't break the requestAnimationFrame max 60 fps. Without it you will see that the fps increases.  Technically it can't go above 60 but the step function runs multiple times in the same frame increasing the velocity each time and making the stars run faster.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var stars = [];
var numOfStars = 10;

function Star(x, y, rad, velocity, fill) {
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999); //this create a random number between 0 and 599 on the x axis
  this.y = 0;
  this.rad = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 15); //this create a random number between 10 and 30 for the radius
  this.velocity = 5;
  this.fill = fill

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    this.y += this.velocity;
  }
}

function createMultipleStars() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= numOfStars; i++) {
    stars[i] = new Star(i * 50, 10, i, i, "rgba(255,215,0,0.6)");
  }
}

function fps() {

  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  fps.frames++;

  if ((now - fps.lastFps) >= 1000) {
    fps.total = fps.frames;
    fps.lastFps = now;
    fps.frames = 0;
  }

  return fps.total;
}

fps.frames = 0;
fps.lastFps = (new Date()).getTime();
fps.total = 0;

// Step is a singleton. Only one instance can be created.
function Step() {
  // comment out the line below to see what happens when not running
  // singleton
  if (Step.instance !== null) return Step.instance;

  var self = this;

  function frame() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i <= numOfStars; i++) {
      stars[i].draw();
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText("FPS: " + fps(), 10, 10);
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  }

  frame();

  Step.instance = this;
  return this;
}

Step.instance = null;


//spaceShip.drawSpaceShip();


function init() {
  var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    createMultipleStars();
    var step = new Step();
  }, 4000);

  createMultipleStars();
  //
  var step = new Step();
  var step = new Step();
  var step = new Step();
  var step = new Step();
}

init();
```

```css
#can {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is very simple : you are using both requestAnimationFrame and setInterval to drive the animation. More and more render loops get created and run at the same time, causing the issue

Separate the concerns :

1. have one render loop working for ever with RequestAnimationFrame
2. Have a setInterval-ed function inject some new stuff in your game.

So the only change you need to do is here :

```
var myVar = setInterval(createMultipleStars, 4000);
```